# Buffered output for fs.readfile() in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

why below code is giving buffered output even though "utf-8" is the default encoding?

```
    fs.readFile('includes/India2011.csv',function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

You have to specify utf-8 encoding like this:

```
fs.readFile('includes/India2011.csv', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

[documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)

Comment: Geez, I was stuck on what was meant by _"buffered output"_ :-)

Comment: By buffer i meant <Buffer 76 61 72 20 66 73 20 3d 20 72 65 71 75 69 72 65 28 27 66 73 27 29 3b 0d 0a 66 73 2e 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 27 68 65 6c 6c 6f 2e 6a 73 27 2c 20 66 ... >

Comment: If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned. hence we need to pass "utf-8" as encoding format.